# issue with category-name/product-name.html format in Magento

Tags: magento

I have created a new module to list categories for a specific reason in my Magento website.
But after implementing the category listing, the products listed under a category has url in the format

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/catalog/product/view/id/2853/s/product-name
```

but it supposed to be `http://www.mywebsite.com/category/product-name`

Also i have checked if the `System > Configuration > Catalog > Search Engine Optimization > Use Categories Path for Product URLs = Enable`

Not sure about the issue. Anyone give me a hand on this?

**Note : I have used the below code to get the product url**

```
$_parentProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($groupedParentId);
$_parentProduct->getProductUrl();
```

**Update : After re-indexing "Catalog URL Rewrites", i could able to see the urls under category product listing like `http://www.mywebsite.com/product-name.html`**

but still cannot able to find a way to make it list like `http://www.mywebsite.com/category/product-name.html`

Thanks,

Balan

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your config cache in magento ( if its enabled)

System > Cache Management > (cache type) configuration ---- flush this.

See this might help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Balan had a similar issue... i tried using this code and helped me to get the complete product url with category names... you may want to try it out..

```
<?php $_categories = $_product->getCategoryIds();
  $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categories[0]); 
$url = $this->getUrl($_category->getUrlPath()).basename($_product->getProductUrl());
       // only problem is this will be /category/category2.html/my-jacket.html
    // so strip the .html and put it on the end
    $url = str_replace(".html","" ,$url) . '.html';?>
```

ultimately, echo $url as so..

```
<?php echo $url ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

System > Index Management > Catelog URL Rewrite > [re-index]